# How to find a key from a dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a dictionary which  contains a key of type `Wall` and a value which is a `List<Tile>`

So it looks like this:

`new Dictionary<Wall, List<Tile>>();`

So i have a Tile and i am wanting to find all Wall types connected to this tile which is buried in the lists.

I don't fully understand how i iterate through the dictionary to do such a thing since the tile is then also inside the list. Should i not be using a Dictionary at all for this kind of data connection, i am not entirely sure if i am understanding dictionaries correctly here.

Comment: `Wall` should be unique if is key. I don't understand how you want to find walls specific `Tile`?

Comment: Well say i have a Tile, and i want to find all Walls that are part of the tile. Since a tile can be surrounded by a maximum of 4 walls. 

I chose this setup because a single wall can have 2 Tiles attached (hence the list) to it since a wall separates a max of 2 tiles.

Comment: Does list of `Tile` represent tiles surrended by same walls?

Comment: @kat1330 Yes so the list only contains a max of two tiles. I should probably really use an array really.

Comment: cant you implement this in structure of Tile and Wall itself? for example Tile having properties `Left, Right, Top, Bottom` so each of these can have reference to a wall. and `Wall` have just `Left, Right` with reference to tiles.

Comment: another way is to use 2d-Matrix. with tiles and walls in it you can mark `0`s as tiles and `1`s as walls

Comment: @Dave You can use dictionary `new Dictionary<Wall, List<Tile>>().SingleOrDefault(EXPRESSION HERE).Key;` but you will need to implement your equality comparer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think a `Dictionary<Wall, List<Tile>>` is the best data structure for solving this problem:

> So i have a Tile and i am wanting to find all Wall types connected to
>   this tile which is buried in the lists

You would have to use brute force (and very poor performance):

```
Dictionary<Wall, List<Tile>> dictionary; //todo initialize
List<Wall> result = new List<Wall>();
foreach (var kvp in dictionary) {
   if (kvp.Value.Contains(tile))
       result.Add(kvp.Key);
}
```

If you have a Tile and want to find a list of Walls, you would want `Dictionary<Tile, List<Wall>>`.

```
Dictionary<Tile, List<Wall>> dictionary; //todo initialize
List<Wall> result = dictionary[tile];
```

Which would leverage the power of the dictionary nicely.

Comment: But is `Tile` reference type? I think you will need to implement equality  comparer.

Comment: Yes, you very likely would need to override Equals() and GetHashCode() for whatever the "Key" is in either example.

Comment: Hmm so i would need a dictionary of Tile, Wall and a dictionary of Wall, Tile since i some times need to find  tiles adjacent to walls as well. This starts to get difficult to keep organise ultimately. Perhaps i need to change my overall structure.

Comment: You likely want an entire different data structure for your problem.  My answer merely illustrates how the `Dictionary` works.

Comment: Yes it does sound like i do. Thanks for the help. :)